# Illustrator: Gaps in path stroke when I fill leaf shape with a color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, fill, pen-tool

[image]

So I used the pen tool to create this leaf. When I fill it, these 'gaps' appear where the strokes should be. How do I fix this? (I'm really new to illustrator)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use a fill for the large, leaf-shaped object. All the other lines on the inside should have no fill, just the outline.